# Reference cell to another sheet cell which has array formula?

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas, google-sheets-formula

I tried to use indirect but it does not work as follow:

```
=ArrayFormula(indirect(Frmla!B1))
```

Sheet name: Frml, cell B1 has the array formula phrase.

Also tried to index the whole array formula but I got an error too

```
=index(Frmla!B1)
```

**Sheet URL:**

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SOsZX-Vrowxc3XlcaeH_7o3FYYFSJY3Wcsagkj5F2Eo/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

try: **`=ArrayFormula(indirect("Frmla!B1"))`**

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SOsZX-Vrowxc3XlcaeH_7o3FYYFSJY3Wcsagkj5F2Eo/edit?usp=sharing